# Однородные и неоднородные определения! Помогите понять разницу! Спасибо большое за ответы

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

однородные и неоднородные определения! Помогите понять разницу! Спасибо большое за ответы

Comment: [*Отвечено, так с плеч долой...*](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/34661/пунктуация-были-в-конторе-старые-висячие-стенные-часы-почему-здесь-определение-неоднородны)

Answer (score 2):

Вы знаете, пересказывать целst параграфы из академических грамматик - это, конечно, интересно.

Я не буду пересказывать все сказанное Софьей, ибо понятно, что ситуация до конца не формализуется. Часто - на то есть воля автора определить, с разных ли сторон характеризуют объект использованные им определения. Пунктуация как раз и позволяет понять, что имеет в виду автор.

Брошу свои пять копеек.

Есть хороший (хоть и не универсальный) признак.
Годится для любого человека с достаточно высокой культурой речи.
Неоднородные определения отличаются тем, что как бы последовательно уточняют объект.
*Большое красное яблоко* - это большое *красное яблоко*, я не просто *большое и красное* яблоко.

Поэтому неоднородные определения обычно следуют в строго определенном порядке.
При попытке изменить его сразу возникает какой-то диссонанс.

*Большое красное яблоко* - нормально. *Красное большое яблоко* звучит странновато -

Comment: Это явление называется последовательным сужением признака, которое свойственно неоднородным  прилагательным. Допустим, из корзины надо достать большое красное яблоко. Сначала берем все красные яблоки, а потом среди них выбираем большое. Именно такая последовательность закрепилась психологически, сужение по размеру делается в последнюю очередь. При обратной последовательности признаки обычно считаются сближенными, а прилагательные - однородными: Мы срывали красные, большие яблоки (раскрывается общая тема качественных фруктов).

Answer (score 1):

ОБЩЕЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ

Однородные определения независимо друг от друга раскрывают общую тем, в то время как неоднородные определения характеризуют предмет с разных сторон.  Для однородных определений характерна перечислительная интонация, а неоднородные определения составляют единую фразу, то есть произносятся без паузы.

1) ОДНОРОДНЫЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ (раскрытие общей темы)

Большинство однородных определений выражено качественными прилагательными (или относительными прилагательными в значении качественных).

А)  Однородные определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными

а)  Определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными, являются однородными, то есть раскрывают общую тему, если они обозначают СХОДНЫЕ или СБЛИЖЕННЫЕ признаки (в этом случае ряд однородных определений можно заменить одним определением с обобщённым значением).

Красные, желтые (= разноцветные) листья кружатся в воздухе, толкаясь резными бочками. 
Всё тонуло в сплошной, беспросветной (= абсолютной) мгле. 
Всё спало крепким, неподвижным, здоровым сном. Наступила ясная, тёплая погода. 
Собака смотрела на зловещий, красный диск луны. 
Люди мечтают о длинном  лете, а я мечтаю о длинной, тёплой, туманной осени.

б) Сближение признаков происходит в конкретном тексте и может обуславливаться ПРИЧИННО-СЛЕДСТВЕННОЙ связью или употреблением прилагательных в качестве МЕТАФОРЫ (образного скрытого сравнения).
   Примечание. Следует отметить, что вопрос о сближении признаков для качественных прилагательных в некоторых случаях может решаться различным образом (авторский вариант).

Стояла тёмная, безлунная ночь (тёмная, так как безлунная). Следы видны в седой, росистой траве. Снова потянулись длинные, однообразные дни. Его поместили в просторной, пустой комнате.

Наконец наступил славный, весёлый май. Была жестокая, холодная зима. По обеим  сторонам дороги неподвижно стоят старые, печальные берёзы. Тяжёлый, пасмурный туман нагие холмы обвивает.

В)  Определения считаются однородными и отделяются запятыми, если определение стоит после определяемого слова. Причиной формального решения является сближение признаков, обусловленное интонационными особенностями (обязательность перечислительной интонации):

Его всегда отталкивало слово высокопарное, фальшивое, книжное. Стены в боярских хоромах дубовые, рубленые. Бог лазурный, чистый, нежный шлёт свои дары. И очи синие, бездонные цветут на дальнем берегу. И  в день морозный, солнечный, красный мы встретились в храме. Я буду тогда обладателем истины вечной, несомненной.

2) НЕОДНОРОДНЫЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ (характеризуют предмет с разных сторон)

Неоднородные определения выражаются различными видами прилагательных: качественными, относительными, притяжательными, а также их различными сочетаниями. 
Примечание. В случае неоднородных определений предшествующее определение относится ко всему последующему словосочетанию, а не непосредственно к существительному, например: Шёл длинный (товарный поезд).

А)Определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными

Определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными, являются неоднородными, если они обозначают разные признаки, не раскрывающие общую тему, например размер и форму, цвет и размер:

На столе стояло маленькое овальное  зеркало. Груз укреплён на тонкой длинной нити. Тёмное чистое небо торжественно и высоко стояло над нами. У девушки была длинная чёрная коса на спине и узкий правильный нос. На западе огромное красное солнце исчезало в туманном горизонте.

Б) Определения, выраженные относительными, притяжательными и качественными прилагательными в различных сочетаниях

Если определения выражены относительными или притяжательными прилагательными, а также при  различных сочетаниях качественных, относительных и притяжательных прилагательных,  они, как правило, являются неоднородными .

Сторож жил в маленьком деревянном домике. Стоят хмурой ратью высокие столетние сосны. Ранняя зимняя заря проступала сквозь мертвенную дымку. В углу стоял круглый полированный стол. Мальчик был в лёгком матросском костюме. За полем сразу начинался густой сосновый лес.

Я поднялся по чердачной железной лестнице. Начинался осенний петербургский день. Туда вела единственная песчаная дорога. Мелькнул пушистый лисий хвост. Он взял отцовское двуствольное ружьё. Среди вещей мне попались мамина вязаная кофта и отцовское шерстяное пальто.